# Preposition problem

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I bought two discounted tickets *on* Standard airlines to Honolulu
Or
I bought two discounted tickets *for* Standard Airlines to Honolulu

Out of the two , Please tell me which one is correct  with regard to preposition.

Answer (score 2):

I bought two discounted Standard Airlines tickets to Honolulu...

Answer (score 1):

*For*.

*X for Y* is used to express that you use X to accomplish, complete, allow, or do Y.  *E.g. I bought tickets for the concert*

*On* sounds like you are trying to say you bought the tickets while on a plane.

Answer (score -4):

Nither of them is correct.
You can write,  i have bought 2 discounted ticket of standerd airlined to Honolulu.
For is used for purpose, as i bought a car for my mother

Comment: This is wrong: "tickets of ..." is grammatically incorrect. I would go with "on," and suggest changing the word order (tickets _to_ Honolulu _on_ Standard Airlines).

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your answer. As you can see this answer is being down voted. As a reviewer, I'd like to give you some tips. The community here values answers that help the learner understand and use English better. This answer has incorrect grammar, is missing punctuation and is not accurate. It's not helpful for the learner.There is a comment with some suggested improvements you could make. I would suggest you follow the suggestion, do more research before answering and make sure your answer reflects good English usage.